# Conditional view of fields in a view model in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following view model to query my table:

QuestionViewModel.cs

```
public enum TypeQuestion {
   Long = 1,
   Short = 2,
   Small = 3,
}

public class QuestionViewModel
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string MaxAge { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string Account { get; set; }

    public TypeQuestion CurrentTypeQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

if the query I'm doing is of type:

Long: displays all fields.
Short: displays Name, LastName, Address, MaxAge.
Small: displays Name, LastName.

Is there any way to put some kind of DataAnnotation to determine which fields to display in the view or some other way?, To avoid putting a "what if?" for each field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-model-classes-with-linq-to-sql-cs) and this [link](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html)

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Consulta()
{
    return View(new QuestionViewModel());
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public enum TypeQuestion {
   Long = 1,
   Short = 2,
   Small = 3,
}

public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int MaxAge { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public TypeQuestion CurrentTypeQuestion { get; set; }

    public bool EnabledField(ModelMetadata field)
    {
        //check pending implementation
        return true;
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MySite.QuestionViewModel
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Collections;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Question";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Question</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "FormQuestion" }))
{

    foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties
        .Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm) && ViewData.Model.EnabledField(pm)))
    {
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml)
        {
            Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName);
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="editor-label">
                @(prop.IsRequired ? "*" : "")
                @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName, prop.Model)
                @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "*")
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be overkill, and i'd in fact lean towards @Mystere Man's answer, but this is another option.

Instead of regular primitive types in your ViewModel, set them up to cater for the logic. Looks like *Name* and *LastName* are **always** displayed, whilst *Address* and *MaxAge* are conditional.

So, setup your ViewModel like this:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ConditionalField> ConditionalFields { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
}

public class ConditionalField
{
   public string Field { get; set; }
   public bool Display { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller, setup the nested viewmodel and the boolean values for *Address* and *MaxAge* ccording to the value of `CurrentTypeQuestion`.

Then, have your View like this:

**/Views/Questions.cshtml**

```
@model QuestionViewModel
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Then create a custom display template (or editor template, if this is a form) for `QuestionViewModel`:

**/Views/DisplayTemplates/QuestionViewModel.cshtml**

```
@model QuestionViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName )
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Category)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Account)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ConditionalFields)
```

Then create *another* custom display template for `ConditionalField`:

**Views/DisplayTemplates/ConditionalField.cshtml**

```
@model ConditionalField
@if (Model.Display) {
   @Html.DisplayForModel()
}
```

As i said, may be overkill, but in the end, you only have a single if statement in the custom template, no loops, and your main view and first-level template stays clean.

Comment: I see this option http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple, and avoid complex if logic in your view, just create three different views, with only the data you need in each view.  Then select the view in your controller based on the question type.

Comment: ok, but in my real case I have 7 options and I need something to avoid creating 7 views

Comment: You either need to have logic in the view to show/not show fields, or you need different views.  There is no magic here.